# Mostrar/Esconder texto al momento de dar click

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Se supone que este codigo debe esconder/mostrar un texto solo al momento de dar click a un input textbox, caso contrario no debe ser mostrado.
 Es algo que considero super sencillo por lo que no quiero ajax, jquery o cuaquier otro tercero. No estoy familiarizado con las funciones que ya vienen implementadas en javascript, alguien podria ayudarme? he buscado por todos lados pero todos ponen soluciones muy complicadas para enfoques diferentes, no he visto nada como este caso que todos vemos al momento de poner una contraseña te dice "debes ingresar de 0-5 caracteres" etc...

```
<label class="tag" for="id_num">Codigo de Identidad<br>
    <!-- DNI PASAPORTE RUC-->
    <input type="text" id="id_num" name="id_num" onclick="id_help()">
    <span id="id_help"></span>
    <script>
        function id_help() {
            var state = document.getElementById("id_num")
            var helper = document.getElementById("id_help").innerHTML = "<br><sup><i>DNI O RUC</i></sup>";
            if (state.onclick === true) {
                helper.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                helper.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</label><br>
```

Comment: No termino de entender la duda, ¿puedes explicar mejor por favor?

Comment: @BetaM tengo un elemento <input> y quiero que solo al dar click a este cuadro de texto me salga abajito "DNI o RUC" como una forma de guiar al usuario. al dejar de tener selecionado este cuadro de texto... la guia que dice "dni o ruc" debe desaparecer

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando sólo JavaScript y bien simple como describís, en lugar de utilizar `onclick`, podés hacer que se muestre el texto con el evento `onfocus` llamando a una función y que se llame a otra función con el evento `onblur` que es su contrario de esta forma

```js
function id_help() {
    document.getElementById("id_help").innerHTML = "block";
}

function exit_id_help() {
    document.getElementById("id_help").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<label class="tag" for="id_num">Codigo de Identidad<br>
<input type="text" id="id_num" name="id_num" onfocus="id_help()" onblur="exit_id_help(this)">
<span id="id_help"></span>
```

Comment: debo añadir que jamas se debe de utilizar gatillos de eventos en html de una sola linea, es un riesgo de seguridad tambien utilizar `innerHTML` la manera correcta es agregar eventListeners a esos dos eventos en el javascript y posteriormente cambiar los `innerHTML` en `textContent`